# Is approximating used car prices with deep learning over-engineering?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, modeling, overfitting

I am supposed to build an application that uses deep learning to approximate prices of used cars. My concern is that deep learning is too general of a tool for the problem at hand.

I am going to use data from sites that sell used cars for training the network. However, looking at the characteristics of each car (age, mileage, previous owners, original price), I fail to see any non-linearity. Here's a few examples:

- the older the car, the lower the price;
- fewer miles, higher price;
- fewer previous owners, higher price.

It would seem to me that a polynomial is enough to model this, as all there is to train is the relative weight of each of the car's characteristics. I don't see any non-linearity that would require anything more sophisticated.

Is there something that I am missing?

**Background information:** This application is part of my thesis (as an undergraduate). I picked this topic out of a predefined list because I have an interest in machine learning, but the subject (used car prices) seems like a poor choice.

Comment: This problem belongs to a field called "residual value" forecasting. You can find a job doing this for car financing companies, I see the job ads all the time in our area. There must be a ton of research, search in Google scholar.

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks, this should be pretty helpful. I did find some articles that seem like they could help me better understand the problem.

Comment: @PaulManta if you find those articles helpful I'd encourage you to answer your own question with a few links and a short summary of what you found

Comment: You could try this with a polynomial first and see if your performance is good enough with a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill, but that is not obvious. I could see the interactions mattering. For instance, adding a year to the age might have more of an impact on the price if the mileage is high, and that impact might not even be constant. You might wind up needing to interact the mileage with a nonlinear function of the age.

Polynomials can fit these patterns, too, and it has been argued that deep learning is just polynomial regression [(Cheng et al, 2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06850). However, neural networks, for better or for worse, make this easy by just throwing a bunch of neurons at the problem and having the network figure out the rest, instead of having to be explicit about which polynomial features are included in a (generalized) linear model.

**REFERENCE**

Cheng, Xi, et al. "Polynomial regression as an alternative to neural nets." arXiv preprint arXiv:1806.06850 (2018).